# How to Pass Generic List of Any Type Through NavComp Fragment Args

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I am converting project from many activities to one activity with many fragments and using navigation component to do so.  There is one activity that accepts multiple lists of about 10 different lists of all different types.  When creating the arguments for the fragment to pass into it how do I do this for an arg that can be any type list?

Here is how I grab it from activity in onCreate.

```
intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>("listItems")
```

I know I will have to do something like this when I send it to the fragment

```
val bundle = bundleOf("ListItems" to (list as ArrayList<out Parcelable>))
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action, bundle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing this.  To me its a bit hacky but it works consistently as long as the lists are not gigantic.

```
binding.button.setOnClickListener {
    val bundle = bundleOf("ListItems" to (list as ArrayList<out Parcelable>))
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_home_to_see_list, bundle)
}
```

And then in the fragment I am passing this data to I just do this

```
val list = arguments?.getParcelableArrayList<ListItems>("ListItems")?.toList()
```

Not happy with this solution as it feels hacky to me but it works

Answer (score 1):

`safeArgs` only support custom `parcelable` and array of custom `parcelable`.

We can't pass generic list using navigation components but we can pass an array of `parcelable`, we can convert a generic list to array using `toTypedArray()`

In navigation graph, change argument type to `array` of custom `parceable` in the destination fragment

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/destinationFragment"
        android:name="com.example.destinationFragments"
        android:label="destinationFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_destination" >
        <argument
            android:name="test"
            app:argType="com.example.data.Test[]" />
 </fragment>
```

Now, you can send your generic list, after converting it to a `TypedArray`

```
 val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToDestinationFragment(list.toTypedArray())
 findNavController().navigate(action)
```

You can receive this in destination fragment using either `savedStateHandle` or `bundle`

Using `bundle`

```
val args: DestinationFragmentArgs by navArgs()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val passesDataArray = args.test //here is your array of custom parcelable
}
```

Comment: Why can't the argType be java.util.ArrayList, stupid that navigation hasn't thought of this that we might want to pass lists to a fragment... stupid Google.  I just pass it into the bundle to the fragment  when using navcomp by -- bundleOf(LISTITEMS to (list as java.util.ArrayList<out Parcelable>) then just use arguments?.getParcelableArrayList<Parcelable>(LISTITEMS)